# Understanding different methods of cloning a stream, and which situation to use which in

Tags: .net, stream

When copying a file stream, I've come across two examples:

This one,

```
Using requestStream as IO.Stream = state.Request.EndGetRequestStream(ar)
    ' Copy the file contents to the request stream.
    Const bufferLength As Integer = 2048
    Dim buffer(bufferLength - 1) As Byte
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    Dim readBytes As Integer = 0
    Using stream As IO.FileStream = IO.File.OpenRead(state.FileName)
        While readBytes <> 0
            readBytes = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength)
            requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, readBytes)
            count += readBytes
        End While
    End Using
End Using
```

and this one:

```
    'Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
    Dim fileContents As Byte()
    Using fileStream As New IO.StreamReader(state.FileName)
        fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileStream.ReadToEnd())
    End Using

    Using requestStream As IO.Stream = state.Request.EndGetRequestStream(ar)
        requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length)
    End Using
```

My understanding is that the first one copies one stream directly to another, the second copies via a byte array. Both work and achieve the same thing. I believe the first one would be quicker, but the second one looks a lot simpler and easier to maintain etc.

I can't see where you set the encoding in the first one though. Why would you need to do it in one, but not the other?

Also, objective comments on the pro's and con's of each snippet would be useful. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second one will *not* work with arbitrary binary data - it treats the data as UTF-8-encoded text data, then re-encodes it - this is a *very bad idea* unless you actually know it's UTF-8-encoded text.

The second form uses a byte array as well, just one buffer at a time.

However, you've got a bug in the first version: you're going to keep going while `bytesRead` is non-zero, but it *starts* as 0.

You might want:

```
Using stream As IO.FileStream = IO.File.OpenRead(state.FileName)
    readBytes = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength)
    While readBytes <> 0
        requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, readBytes)
        count += readBytes
        readBytes = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength)
    End While
End Using
```

In C# I'd use:

```
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength)) > 0)
{
    requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
    count += readBytes;
}
```

but I don't know whether you can do a compound assignment like that in VB.

Some other options:

- You can use [`File.ReadAllBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx) to read a whole file as a byte array, although obviously that will waste memory if it's a large file. This is a sort of safe version of your second code.
- You can use [`Stream.CopyTo(Stream)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.copyto.aspx) if you're using .NET 4. If not, you could potentially write the same code yourself as an extension method to be reused from other projects.

Comment: What kind of buffer size would you recommend having? (if you do not know the typical file size being used)

Comment: @Magnus: I typically use 8 or 16K. Don't go over about 80K as otherwise the buffer will end up on the large object heap.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you, great comment and answer, I shall use your example, but with a while loop as I have a irrational aversion to do loops.

Comment: @MrShoubs: Actually I've fixed the code to use a while loop anyway - I changed my mind half way through writing the do while version; I'm not sure why I kept it.